# How do I style CSS subnav without affecting Main Nav

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/uuyVY/

screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzUPk.png

I am trying to get the subnav to be all white and span the entire contaning div (which is 1100px wide), with just the text links vertically displayed, but cannot get the subnav li background image to turn off without effecting the main nav background image.

```
    ul#horiznav, #horiznav ul {
    /*remove the bullets from the dropdown ul as well*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:53px;
     font-size:10px;
}
#horiznav li {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    position:relative
    /*set position:relative as the start point for absolutely positioning the dropdown*/
}
#horiznav li a {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#horiznav li.trees a, #horiznav li.trees {
    width:198px;
    height:53px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/7Urmvtg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.lights a, #horiznav li.lights {
    width:55px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/dB0kyqA.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.ornaments a, #horiznav li.ornaments {
    width:84px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/OKAhP2U.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#ornamentsSUB li a, #horiznav li a:hover;
 #horiznav li {
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;
}
#horiznav li.wreaths a, #horiznav li.wreaths {
    width:138px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/G9iZZoB.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.christmasdecor a, #horiznav li.christmasdecor {
    width:163px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/9W1q97q.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.commercial a, #horiznav li.commercial {
    width:90px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/2Hcpq1X.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.homedecor a, #horiznav li.homedecor {
    width:90px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/cy5BO92.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.outdoor a, #horiznav li.outdoor {
    width:112px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/fLRrWMs.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.otherholiday a, #horiznav li.otherholiday {
    width:111px;
    height:45px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/AjGVCeK.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li.more a, #horiznav li.more {
    width:69px;
    height:53px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/V1Y7kCy.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#horiznav li a:hover {
    color:#333333
}
#horiznav li ul {
    display:none;
    /*hide the dropdown*/
    position:absolute;
    /*position it absolutely..*/
    left:0;
    /*...align the left edge with the left edge of the parent li...*/
    top:35px
    /*...and 32px down from the top - 30px height + 2px for the border*/
}
#horiznav li:hover ul {
    display:block
    /*display the ul when the parent li is hovered*/
}
#horiznav li ul a {
    background-color:white;
    background-image:none;
    color:#000000;
}



 <div id="navWrap">
    <ul id="horiznav">
        <li class="trees"><a href="#">ARTIFICIAL CHRISTMAS TREES</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lights"><a href="#">LIGHTS</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ornaments"><a href="#">ORNAMENTS</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="wreaths"><a href="#">WREATHS &amp; GARLAND</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="christmasdecor"><a href="#">CHRISTMAS DECORATIONS</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="commercial"><a href="#">COMMERCIAL</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="homedecor"><a href="#">HOME DECOR</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="outdoor"><a href="#">OUTDOOR LIVING</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="otherholiday"><a href="#">MORE HOLIDAYS</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="more"><a href="#">MORE...</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4.3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add background-color to the nav? Also, you may be able to use z-index if you really need to.

Comment: there is background color added to the 

#horiznav li ul a {
    background-color:white;
    background-image:none;
    color:#000000;

which displays in the area not covered by the image.

Comment: The background area you specified is the text within the menu. It can't have a background image anyways.

Comment: added screenshot to help explain: http://i.imgur.com/wMzSQ1B.png

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#horiznav li:hover ul a
{
    background: white;
    color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly in regards to getting rid of the background image! 

Is there anyway to get the subnav nested into a larger div that occupies the width of the screen? Something like this:

http://www.wayfair.com/